# Update or insert in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, insert

how to update a field in a document if the field already exists else update the value of the field? $set updates fine on documents where the field already exists. just found lot of hints how to insert a new field into an entire collection but how to solve this on document basis?

Regards,
Chris

Comment: You seem to be asking something redundant - if the field exists how do I update a field? else, if it doesn't exist how do I update the value of the field?  You just use $set either way, it doesn't matter if the field already existed in the document or not.

Comment: OK, it works! Here's the example for ppl with same issue (I'm running the Moped Ruby Driver):

`irb> users.find.one
 => {"username"=>"kamatei", "_id"=>"a407ebb3d89abd380ddda074cf03b9e4"}`

What I need is:

`{"username"=>"kamatei", "age"=>"26", "_id"=>"a407ebb3d89abd380ddda074cf03b9e4"}`

Updating via $set:

`users.find(_id: "a407ebb3d89abd380ddda074cf03b9e4").update(:$set => {age: 26})`

... ends with

`{"_id"=>"a407ebb3d89abd380ddda074cf03b9e4", "age"=>26, "username"=>"kamatei"}`

Thanks a lot for help!

Comment: you might want to accept the answer below that summarizes this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[$set](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/set/) will add the specified field or fields if they do not exist in this document or replace the existing value of the specified field(s) if they already exist.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [upsert](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/update/#update-operations-with-the-upsert-flag) flag in your update statement.

Comment: upsert flag says whether to create the document if there is no match to update.  kind of unrelated to the original question.